# Adding 2 same elements after div

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to add 2 `<br>` tags immediately after my `<div>` tag. Here is what I am doing presently:

```
var elementDiv = document.createElement("div");
var elementBr = document.createElement("br");
var elementBr1 = document.createElement("br");
elementDiv.appendChild(elementBr);
elementDiv.appendChild(elementBr1);
```

Is there a quick way to do this? I am trying avoid creating 2 separate elements for 'br' and then appending it to 'div' twice. Sorry am noob in Javascript.

With this code here is what I am seeing in final html:

```
<div>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: you can append twice the same br instead of creating two

Comment: `appendChild` appends it to that element, not after it.

Comment: I tried that and when I looked at final html I just saw one in there.

Comment: @BipBip, no you can't.  Appending a node that is already in the DOM removes it from its parent before appending to the new parent.  [MozDev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) says "if the node already has a parent, it is first removed, then appended at the new position."

Comment: Just looking at the code youa re trying to do there makes me feel uneasy. Why would you ever add 2 "br" to the dome? Just use margin or something. Try to learn proper ways before slapping stuff together

Comment: @Tom - I was trying to add a line space. I learnt that one 'br' tag doesn't help for that as one 'br' moves the stuff to new line and 2 'br' is used to add a line space. However 'margin' property looks good in this case instead of using 2 'br'. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @tech_human No problem, if I may share something else, first learn solid grounds of web development, then whenever you run into some problem search the internet  and only then come over here and ask questions. I am not blaming for asking, but this is very VERY basic stuff of web development, you should know this before you know what stackoverflow is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
elementDiv.innerHTML += "<br><br>";
```

or more elegant

```
for (co=0; co<2; co++) elementDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

```
var elementDiv = document.createElement('div');
elementDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br/><br/>');
```